# R: finding the range of inputs for a function that give a certain range of outputs

Tags: r, function, range, beta-distribution

I'm using pbeta(), the cumulative probability distribution fuction in R, to find the probabilities of input values (p) from 0-1. I'm interested in just a subset of those input values that give probabilities between 0.025 and 0.975 (this is a confidence interval for my data).

My initial approach was to list 99 values between 0 and 1 and run pbeta() on them, and then extract those values which had outputs in the right range:

```
alpha <- 50 # Set values for the other two pbeta() parameters.
beta <- 100

p <- c(seq(from=0.01, to=0.99, by=0.01)) # Inputs must be between 0.01 and 0.99 inclusive, so evaluate 99 points in that range.
pbeta_outputs <- c(rep(0,99)) # A vector to hold the pbeta() output.

for (i in seq(1:length(p)) ) { # Fill pbeta_outputs using pbeta().
  pbeta_outputs[i] <- pbeta(p[i], shape1=alpha, shape2=beta)
}

probabilities <- data.frame(p, pbeta_outputs) # Arrange inputs and outputs in a data frame.
probabilities_keep <- subset(probabilities, pbeta_outputs>=0.025 & pbeta_outputs<=0.975)  # Subset to keep only inputs with outputs in the right range.
```

But, this is imprecise. Instead, I'd like to directly calculate the range of input values that would produce pbeta() output in the right range.

Something like:

```
successful_inputs <- find_input_range(pbeta(x, shape1=alpha, shape2=beta), 0.025:0.975)
```

Does a function like this exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you are looking for is `qbeta`?

```
alpha <- 50
beta <- 100

# get lower bound 
(lb <- qbeta(0.025, shape1 = alpha, shape2 = beta))
# [1] 0.2603782

# get upper bound
(ub <- qbeta(0.975, shape1 = alpha, shape2 = beta))
# [1] 0.4104985

pbeta(ub, shape1 = alpha, shape2 = beta) - pbeta(lb, shape1 = alpha, shape2 = beta)
# [1] 0.95
```

Comment: Fantastic. This completely solves my problem, and from an angle I hadn't thought of. Thank you!